# How to use a variable in .twig syntax

Tags: php, twig, slim, twig-extension

I am to DRY in a twig template. I am wondering is you can access a variable in the {{ notation }} of twig.

For example:

```
{% if page.lang == 'en' %}
   // do something 
   {{ content_en }}
{% endif %}
{% if page.lang == 'es' %}
    // hacer algo 
    {{ content_es }}
{% endif %}
```

I tried some other approaches. But is it possible to (somehow) combine variables and do something like this:

```
// Php example
$var = 'content_';
$var .= page.lang;
// Output would be 'content_en';
```

But then for Twig?

```
// Something like 
{{ content_ + page.lang }}
```

To make it more clear. I would like to access to correct variable.

```
$content_en = 'this is just some content';
$content_es ='Alguna información';
$var = 'content_';
$var .= 'en';

$key = ${$var};
// Output is 'this is just some content'
echo $key;
```

Comment: So you want to concatenate variables?

Comment: Actually there is a variable that is called content_en, content_es. Just want to access that variable without all the if, if else, ... etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to concatenate the output you need to use `~`

```
{{ 'content_' ~ page.lang }}
```

If you want to call a dynamic variable you need to use `attribute`

```
{{ attribute(_context, 'content_' ~ page.lang) }}
```

---

*`_context` is a special variable in twig which containts all variables you passed towards the template*

Comment: {{ content ~ '_' ~ page.lang }} gives me only '_en' in stead of the data.
{{ attribute(_context, content ~ '_' ~ page.lang) }} does not give me anything actually

Comment: Sorry mistaken `content` for a variable as well, should be a string. Updated answer ([twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/6mcp2h))

Comment: Thanks Darkbee!
The {{ 'content_' ~ page.lang }} now gives the right name. How can I access the var?
the attribute -line does not work @ Slim?

Comment: Should work on any framework as the answer is based pure on twig. You did pass that variable to the template right?

Comment: Yes. There is a $content_en, $content_es variable. But i stead if a lot of 'if', 'elseif' i would like to DRY.

But at this moment the output is the var name. Still have to access it.

Comment: Watch the fiddle here, https://twigfiddle.com/6mcp2h, it can't be more DRY than that :)

Comment: Hi DarkBee,

Not sure why. But it does not work. I only get the full name printed out.

Comment: You made use of the 2nd snippet right, with the `attribute` function?

Comment: Yes, i did.

{{ page.city.name_nl }} // 'Amsterdam'
<br>
{{ 'page.city.name_' ~ page.lang }}    // 'page.city.name_nl '
{{ attribute(_context, 'page.city.name_' ~ page.lang) }}    // nothing ?

I also checked:
{{ attribute(_context, 'page.city.name_' ~ page.lang) is defined ? 'Method exists' : 'Method does not exist' }}

Output: Method does not exist ?

Comment: its `_context` not `context`

Comment: Hi Darkbee,

Strange. Don't know why the underscore is removed in my comment. Because it is there in the .twig-file.
```php
{{ 'page.city.name_' ~ page.lang }}
{{ attribute(_context, 'page.city.name_' ~ page.lang) }}
```
```php
{{ attribute(_context, 'page.city.name_' ~ page.lang) is defined ? 'Method exists' : 'Method does not exist' }}
// Method does not exist

```
```php
{% if page.city.name_nl is defined %}
{{'Method exists'}}
{% endif %}
// Method exists
```

Answer (score 0):

@Darabee.

You are correct, the syntax would be:

```
{{ attribute(_context, 'content_' ~ page.lang) }}
```

But how ever I noticed that if there is a array and u use '.' instead of a underscore '_' it will not work.

In my case I have a multi-array. That is the issue.

```
page['city']['content_en'].
or page.city.content_en
```